# Problems Implementing CleanTalk

Tags: java, php, html, forms

I am trying to implement an online service called CleanTalk which requires me to deploy scripts on my boss' website pages. CleanTalk prevents spambots from filling out website forms and email signup fields. I followed their instructions carefully but have been unsuccessful in getting it to work.

If I put the script before any HTML code, all the following html on the rest of the page doesn't get displayed. When I put the code at the end of the page, then I can see all the HTML, fill out the form and submit it, but nothing goes through. There are also no spambot blockings recorded in my CleanTalk account, even when I use their spam email tester in the form fields.

Here is the php code provided by CleanTalk:

```
 <!--CLEANTALK SCRIPT-->
    <?php
    session_start();
    require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '../javajq/cleantalk.class.php');
    // Take params from config
    $config_url = 'http://moderate.cleantalk.org/api2.0/';
    $auth_key = 'nere2usu5ehe'; // Set Cleantalk auth key
    if (count($_POST)) {
    $sender_nickname = 'John Dow';
    if (isset($_POST['login']) && $_POST['login'] != '')
    $sender_nickname = $_POST['login'];
    $sender_email = 'stop_email@example.com';
    if (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != '')
    $sender_email = $_POST['email'];
    $sender_ip = null;
    if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
    $sender_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $js_on = 0; 
    if (isset($_POST['js_on']) && $_POST['js_on'] == date("Y"))
    $js_on = 1;
    $message = null; 
    if (isset($_POST['message']) && $_POST['message'] != '')
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    // The facility in which to store the query parameters
    $ct_request = new CleantalkRequest();
    $ct_request->auth_key = $auth_key;
    $ct_request->agent = 'php-api';
    $ct_request->sender_email = $sender_email; 
    $ct_request->sender_ip = $sender_ip; 
    $ct_request->sender_nickname = $sender_nickname; 
    $ct_request->js_on = $js_on;
    $ct_request->message = $message;
    $ct_request->submit_time = time() - (int) $_SESSION['ct_submit_time'];
    //Additional parameters. You could the description at the bottom of the page.
    $ct = new Cleantalk();
    $ct->server_url = $config_url;
    // Check
    $ct_result = $ct->isAllowMessage($ct_request);
    if ($ct_result->allow == 1) {
    echo 'Message allowed. Reason ' . $ct_result->comment;
    } else {
    echo 'Message forbidden. Reason ' . $ct_result->comment;
    }
    echo '<br /><br />';
    }
    else
    {
    $_SESSION['ct_submit_time'] = time();
    }
    ?>
    <!--CLEANTALK SCRIPT-->
```

And here is my html form code with the CleanTalk code I am required to add to it:

```
  <!--CONTACT FORM--> 
<form action="form.php" method="post" name="contact form" style="padding-bottom: 55px;">
    <br>
    <input class="formstyle round bgcolor purpleb" style="width: 631px;" type="text" name='name' placeholder="Full Name" required><br>

    <!-- ADDED value="" TO THE EMAIL SECTION.-->
    <input class="formstyle round bgcolor purpleb" type="email" name='email' required placeholder="Email" value="" style="float: left; width: 295px; margin-right: 15px;">

    <input class="formstyle round bgcolor purpleb" type="tel" name='tel' required placeholder="Phone" style="float: left; width: 295px;"> <br>
    <textarea class="formstyle round bgcolor purpleb messagebox" type="text" name='message' required style="height: 160px;" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="spambot" name="spambot" value="Yes" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label for='spambot'><span class="parastyle grey">Yes, I'm human</span></label>
    <br /><br />

    <!--For Cleantalk-->
    <input type="hidden" name="js_on" id="js_on" value="0" />

    <input type="submit" class="purpleb round formstyle bgcolor sendform" value="SEND" name='submit' style="float:left">
    <label for='submit'><a class="reco grey" href="/privacy" target="_blank"><span style="text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>PRIVACY POLICY</a></label>

    <!--For Cleantalk-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var date = new Date();
    document.getElementById("js_on").value = date.getFullYear(); 
    </script>

</form>
   <!--CONTACT FORM-->
```

Here is a [link to the CleanTalk API installation instructions](https://cleantalk.org/help/api-main). If you need anything else just let me know.

Here are the error message I'm getting:

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /hermes/bosnacweb01/bosnacweb01bh/b2702/myd.bkholodov/public_html/webservice2/contact/index2.php:19) in /hermes/bosnacweb01/bosnacweb01bh/b2702/myd.bkholodov/public_html/webservice2/contact/index2.php on line 72

Warning: require_once(/hermes/bosnacweb01/bosnacweb01bh/b2702/myd.bkholodov/public_html/webservice2/contact../javajq/cleantalk.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /hermes/bosnacweb01/bosnacweb01bh/b2702/myd.bkholodov/public_html/webservice2/contact/index2.php on line 73

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/hermes/bosnacweb01/bosnacweb01bh/b2702/myd.bkholodov/public_html/webservice2/contact../javajq/cleantalk.class.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php-5.5.22-amd64/lib/php') in /hermes/bosnacweb01/bosnacweb01bh/b2702/myd.bkholodov/public_html/webservice2/contact/index2.php on line 73

Comment: "I followed their instructions carefully but have been unsuccessful in getting it to work.". Could you be more specific? What happened?

Comment: What doesn't work and are you seeing any errors in your logs?

Comment: @mhvelplund Thank you for asking, I have edited my question with more information.

Comment: @ficuscr Thank you for asking, I have revised the question with more information.